# initialization of an array of objects in a for loop, this cause all the objects have the same values, help please

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to initialize an array of objects in a for loop, each object with a different value that comes from the console, I have a for loop to do this and everything is ok until I see the objects, all the objects have the values of the second input, I have tried a lot of different things but I can't see what's wrong, I'm 17 years old and a total beginner, I'm not a native English speaker so sorry if is hard to understand, sorry if the solution is obvious.
Please help me, Thank you.

This is my main class code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockDriver {
 
    static Stocks stockObj[];
    static int NumStocks;
    static String Symbol;
    static String ComName;
    static int Shares;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many stocks do you want to create?");
        //Stocks input
        try { //Try-Catch to handle Imput Mismatch Exeption 
                NumStocks = cin.nextInt();
                cin.nextLine();
                System.out.println("You entered: " + NumStocks);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Stock");
        }
        System.out.println("You will now enter in the company symbol, name and their share quantity. The price will be randomly generated.");
        
        //Initialitation of stock objects 
        stockObj = new Stocks[NumStocks];

        //For loop to ask for the imput of all stock, forced to a maximum of 10 stocks 
        for(int i = 0; i < NumStocks && i < 10; i++){
               
            stockObj[i] = new Stocks(Symbol,ComName,Shares);


            //Symbol input
        
            System.out.println("Please enter the three character symbol: ");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Imput Mismatch Exeption 
                Symbol = cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Symbol");
            }

            //Company Name input

            System.out.println("Please enter the conpany name:");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Imput Mismatch Exeption 
                ComName = cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Name");
            }

            //Number of Shares input
            
            System.out.println("Please enter the total shares:");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Input Mismatch Exeption 
                Shares = cin.nextInt();
                cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Shares");
            }
            
            // stockObj[i] = new Stocks(Symbol,ComName,Shares);

        }

        for( int i = 0; i < NumStocks;i++){
            System.out.println("this is "+i);
            System.out.println(stockObj[i].getSymbol());
        }
        
    }


}
```

This a class for my program.

```
public class Stocks {
    private static String Symbol;
    private static String ComName;
    private static int Shares;
    private static double price;


    Stocks(String symbol, String comName, int shares) {

        Symbol = symbol;
        ComName = comName;
        Shares = shares;

    }

    //Method to get symbol
    public String getSymbol(){
        return Symbol;
    }

    //Method to get Company Name 
    public String getComName(){
        return ComName;
    }

    //Method to get the random price between $1.00 and $200.99
    public double randomPrice(){

        double price = (Math.random() * (200.99 - 1.00)) + 1.00;
        Stocks.price = price;
        return price;
    }
    
    //Method to get Shares
    public int getShares(){
        return Shares;
    }
    
    //Method to get the total value of the stock 
    public double totalValue(){
        return price * Shares;
    }


}
```

In the next for loop I ask for three inputs the number of times that was entered before, what I tried to do is to store the inputs the first time of the loop and create a object with this inputs before the loop ask for the inputs again and the inputs change. I have verified and the program does store different inputs so this is no the problem. The problem is that when a take a look at each object have the same values although there were different inputs, the input that is stored in  all objects is one before the last one or the last one. I would like understand what's going on and know a way to store the different inputs in the objects, thank you very much and sorry for the long reading.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumStocks && i < 10; i++){
               
            //stockObj[i] = new Stocks(Symbol,ComName,Shares);


            //Symbol input
        
            System.out.println("Please enter the three character symbol: ");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Imput Mismatch Exeption 
                Symbol = cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Symbol");
            }

            //Company Name input

            System.out.println("Please enter the conpany name:");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Imput Mismatch Exeption 
                ComName = cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Name");
            }

            //Number of Shares input
            
            System.out.println("Please enter the total shares:");
            try { //Try-Catch to handle Input Mismatch Exeption 
                Shares = cin.nextInt();
                cin.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("That is an improper value. The program has been stoped.");
                cin.close();
                System.err.println(e + "in Shares");
            }
            
            stockObj[i] = new Stocks(Symbol,ComName,Shares);

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you stepped through the code in your debugger to see where its behavior differs from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the fields in `Stocks` class are `static`, that is, they exist *per class* -- not per instance, and therefore the same values are shared across all instances when they are created.

To fix the issue, just remove `static` modifier, and change the field names to be `camelCase` to comply with Java naming conventions:

```java
public class Stocks {
    private String symbol;
    private String comName;
    private int shares;
    private double price;
// ...
// update getters/setters/constructor according to the updated field names
}
```